# plot window showing up when run from terminal in Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm using Plots.jl with the default backend to plot an image and save the figure.

```
using Plots: plot, savefig
plot(rangex,rangey,some_image,xticks,yticks,...);
savefig("name.jpg");
```

this works perfectly fine with Juno IDE. But my final code is expected to run in the terminal. When I try to run the same code in terminal it becomes super slow and in each plot I see a GKS QtTerm window appear and disappear for a moment. Is there a way to disable this window?

**EDIT:** Here are my runtime results.

**In Atom Juno:**

- starting julia + loading libraries & functions took about 36s
- doing 100 plot iterations took about 55s
- total of **91** seconds.

**In Windows cmd:**

- starting julia + loading libraries & functions took about 21s
- doing 100 plot iterations took about 284 seconds
- total of **305** seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 150x increase in the performance set null device as the gr output.

```
ENV["GKSwstype"]="nul"
```

This needs to be done before initializing the `gr()` backend.

Here are the times on my machine:

```
using Plots
gr()
savefig(plot(rand(10)),"myplot.png")
@time savefig(plot(rand(10)),"myplot.png");
```

yields:

```
2.388764 seconds (25.38 k allocations: 936.133 KiB)
```

```
using Plots
ENV["GKSwstype"]="nul"
gr()
savefig(plot(rand(10)),"myplot.png")
@time savefig(plot(rand(10)),"myplot.png");
```

yields:

```
0.016462 seconds (24.22 k allocations: 877.680 KiB)
```

Eeasy as that and 150x times faster!

Addtional note. If you want to minimize the time to the first plot compile `Plots.jl` inside your Julia sysismage. Here is my other SO answer explaining how [Why julia takes long time to import a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752978/why-julia-takes-long-time-to-import-a-package)